# Where to ask about Team Foundation Server and Visual Studio problems?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to ask some questions about Team Foundation Server and Visual Studio. I asked questions in Visual Studio Community but it seems to take long time to answer(compared to stack overflow). I wanted to know whether there is a place to ask such questions. I once asked in stack overflow but got down vote because that wasn't a real programming question.

So where can I ask my question?

Comment: It's always easier for us if you also include a sample question  that you would like to ask (or link to your SO question). In general Team Foundation Server and Visual Studio could be on topic for SO as they are tools commonly used by programmers so we'd need to see what you're asking to see what's going wrong.

Comment: This is the link of my question https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3da1812f-eb80-484c-9358-409b6551e8c0/connecting-to-tfs-server-error-1002-and-1003?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Comment: @programmer21 the answer you got there is right - contact your TFS administrator.